# Creating a searchbar for mat-cards in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, search, angular-material

My angular project is essentially a bunch of mat-cards that hold some buttons and images. When the button is clicked it directs you to another website. Pretty basic. The code is like this:

```
<mat-card id="CARDBOX" *ngFor="let box of box">
                      <img class="logoy" src="{{box.image}}" alt="Tesla" height=35px>
                      <a href="{{box.link}}" class="button">{{box.button_name}}</a>
                      <input type="image" id="info" title="Click for description" src="{{box.info}}" height=20px/>
</mat-card>
```

It looks like this
[image: Example]

I would like to add a search bar at the top of the page so that one can search for a certain link and access it from the autocomplete dropdown that would accompany the search bar. I.e. if one types "Example" then the autocomplete would give Example1, Example2, Example3, and you could click on that and it would link you to the appropriate website the same way that clicking the button on the mat-card would. Is there some kind of library that makes this easy? Or do I have to implement it in the backend? Is this possible to do in Angular? I haven't been able to find any documentation on the matter. If so, how should I go about implementing this into my project?

Comment: do want to filter the cards or show content links in the dropdown?

Comment: Would like to see the name of the card in the dropdown, and then when I click on the name it will link me to the website, if that's possible. If that's not possible, I would be content with anything really if you have another suggestion.

Comment: Since your already Using `Angular Material` you can use [Material Autocomplete][https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview] for this.

Comment: How would I go about implementing that? At least to start? I create a searchbar object and use Material Autocomplete? Could you post something in the answer section for me? I'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Use angular material `Autocomplete`.

Following will be your search bar.

```html
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

this will be your typescript code.

```
 myControl = new FormControl();
  options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
```

full example from angular material [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/onljnxyyogy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.ts)

_filter function without showing result at first

```
  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
   if(filterValue == ''){
      return []
    }
    return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
```

Comment: Will clicking on my option link me to outside of the page?

Comment: use `window.open('url')` on select event

Comment: Is there a way so that the options will not display at the beginning?

Comment: Are there imports that I need to make? In my TypeScript I am getting a number of errors.

Comment: yes you need to import necessary modules in your `app.module`. ex - `MatAutocompleteModule`

Comment: I added this to an existing component that was used for a toolbar header, because I wanted the search bar to be inside of the header. But it didn't work. Do I need to create a new component for this?

Comment: I got this to work, but it will only work on the first try. Is there a way to get it to reset so it can be used unlimited?

Comment: no it should work more than once. if you check the stackblitz example you can see its working more than once.i can't help you without seen your code.may be create a stackblitz of your code so i can check what's wrong.